# MFMailComposer toReceiptsText with delay

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using MFMailcomposeViewController for the mail functionality. 
but when app present MFMailComposeViewController the text in toReceipts filed display with delay.why is that so ?

```
if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()
  {
    var mailPicker = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailPicker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    mailPicker.setSubject("hello");
    mailPicker.setMessageBody(txtViewBody.text, isHTML: false);
    mailPicker.setToRecipients(["aashish01cs@gmail.com"])

    self.becomeFirstResponder();


    presentViewController(mailPicker, animated: true, completion: {
        println("Mail composer completion block")
    });

    }
```

Comment: Question is still relevant now, and the accepted answer does not provide any manner of serviceable solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It will show Recipient with delay in Simulator.
In device it won't load with delay.

Comment: Hi another problem is that when MFMailComposeViewController display to receipt texfield goes in and then it comes at correct position. do you know how to solve it.

Comment: This is clearly and demonstrably incorrect. This should not be the accepted answer as it brings no serviceable solution to the query.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to prevent the jumpy presentation of the MFMailComposeViewController is with private api calls, but the app will be rejected...

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposeVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    // do your setup here

    UIViewController *internalComposeVC = (UIViewController *) [mailComposeVC.viewControllers firstObject];
    // call private method to layout the view immediately
    SEL privateSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"_endDelayingCompositionPresentation");
    if ([internalComposeVC respondsToSelector:privateSelector]) {
        ((void (*)(id, SEL))[internalComposeVC methodForSelector:privateSelector])(internalComposeVC, privateSelector);
    }

    // present the MFMailComposeViewController
    [self presentViewController:mailComposeVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];

    // while presenting force the controller to set the recipient immediately
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [internalComposeVC viewWillAppear:FALSE];
        [internalComposeVC viewDidAppear:FALSE];
    });
```

I only tested it with iOS 8